# Creating vertical column table in RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, report, rdlc

A typical table in RDLC looks like this:

```
          Type     Date

  #1      Data1    Data2

  #2      Data3    Data4
```

I'd like to display the columns vertically instead of above:

```
           #1       #2        

Type      Data1    Data3

Date      Data2    Data4
```

I couldn't find any options in the table properties. How can I create the above table without introducing some ugly hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a candidate for a Matrix report. Here is simple explanation: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/matrices/